# Проблема с getJSON

Tags: json, ajax, javascript

у меня 3 select'a:
страна, регион, город
При выборе страны должен обновляться select регион относительность страны.
вот такой код. вроде написано логично. но регион не обновляется

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('select[name=ad_country]').change(function() {
        current_country = $(this).val();

        $.getJSON('./core/AJAX/advertisement_changecountry.php', {country: current_country}, 
            function(data) {
                $('select[name=ad_region]').empty();

                $.each(data.region, function(key, val) {
                    $('select[name=ad_region]').append('<option value="'+val.id_parent+'">'+val.name+'</option>');
                });

                $('select[name=ad_city]').empty();

                $.each(data.city, function(key, val) {
                    $('select[name=ad_city]').append('<option value="'+val.id_parent+'">'+val.name+'</option>');
                });
            });
        }
    );
}
```

код файла advertisement_changecountry.php

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] != 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    die("ERROR!");

} else {

    session_start();
    set_time_limit(0);

    $explode  = explode("/", $_SESSION['sessiontpl']);
    $language = $explode[0];

    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    define('ROOT_DIR', str_replace(DS . 'core' . DS . 'AJAX', '', dirname(__FILE__)));
    define("ADON_DIR", ROOT_DIR . DS . "addons");
    define("CLSS_DIR", ROOT_DIR . DS . "core" . DS . "classes" . DS);

    include_once ROOT_DIR . DS . "core" . DS . "data" . DS . "config.php";
    include_once ROOT_DIR . DS . "core" . DS . "data" . DS . "db.config.php";
    include_once CLSS_DIR . "mysqli.class.php";
    include_once CLSS_DIR . "main.class.php";

    $array = array();

    $a = 0;

    $query = $db->query("SELECT id_parent, name_$language as name FROM ani_country WHERE pre_parent = '" . intval($_GET['country']) . "' and pre_pre_parent = 0 and id_parent != 1319");

    while ($row = $db->get_row($query)) {
        if ($a == 0) {
            $sec_id = $row['id_parent'];
            $a      = 1;
        }
        $array['region'][] = $row;
    }

    $query = $db->query("SELECT id_parent, name_$language as name FROM ani_country WHERE pre_parent = '" . intval($_GET['country']) . "' and pre_pre_parent = '" . intval($sec_id) . "' and pre_parent !=1319 and id_parent != 1319");

    while ($row = $db->get_row($query)) {
        $array['city'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: Какой приходит JSON в ответ?

Comment: добавил...

Comment: Я спрашивал - какой в ответ приходит JSON, а не какой у вас PHP-код.

Comment: я просто в jsone не бум-бум. Можно подробнее

Comment: Чему равняется строка `json_encode($array);`? Сделайте `var_dump(json_encode($array));` и дополните вопрос.